# android permision declaration not working on android 13 but works on android 10

Tags: java, android, xml, permissions, sdk

I'm developing an Android app with a minimum SDK version set to Android Nougat (API level 24). I've declared permissions in the manifest file, and they seem to work fine on devices running Android 10 (API level 29). However, when I test the app on devices running Android 13 (API level 32), the permissions don't seem to be working as expected.

Here's a summary of the issue:

Permissions are declared in the manifest file using the  tag.
The app's target SDK version is set to Android 13.
The permissions are essential for the app's functionality, such as accessing the camera or storage.
On Android 13 devices, the app doesn't prompt users for these permissions, leading to functionality issues.
I've reviewed the Android documentation and made sure that I'm following the recommended practices for declaring and requesting permissions. However, I'm still encountering this issue specifically on Android 13 devices.

Could someone please provide insights into why permissions declared in the manifest might work on Android 10 but not on Android 13? Are there any specific changes or considerations introduced in Android 13 that might affect permission handling?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Reefind"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".PartnerInfosActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BusinessNextRegister"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BrowsePartnersActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AddPostActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BusinessHomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ClientHomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AdminHomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BusinessRegisterAcitivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ClientRegisterActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgetPasswordActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ClientOrBusinessActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OnBoardingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseLanguageActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is screenshot from  android 13
[image]

Comment: Are you actually requesting the permissions? You can't do that with just manifest declarations. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: yes i am requesting permision it request permision sucessfully on android 10 but it says permision denied on android 13

Comment: It would be helpful to share the code. Storage permissions changed in Android 13, it could well be related to that. What is your target sdk?

Comment: See also [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13?hl=en#granular-media-permissions).